# Multiple proxy reverse for one Virtual Host

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I have a server which we use to test some services. It's basically a server where devs can run some containers in order to run some tests.

What I'm trying to do is proxy reverse some url patterns into some containers.

For example, this is what I have now:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName dev.server.com

       RewriteEngine On

       RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
       ServerName dev.server.com

       <--- certificates and log configs --->

       SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
       ProxyRequests     On
       ProxyPreserveHost On
       RewriteEngine     On

       ProxyPass /appOne http://localhost:9999/
       ProxyPassReverse /appOne http://localhost:9999/

       ProxyPass /appTwo http://localhost:9000/
       ProxyPassReverse /appTwo http://localhost:9000/

       ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
       ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I access `https://dev.server.com/appOne`, it access the app deployed on port `3000` instead of the one deployed on port `9999`.

I've never configured Apache before, so I'm struggling to understand all the concepts. Is this possible? If yes, where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is certainly possible.  In fact, using a configuration substantially identical to what you've posted, I can't reproduce the problems you've described -- everything seems to work as you want.

I've put a complete example [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-46916024) as a [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) application; it starts up four containers:

- One apache instance acting as a frontend with the ProxyPass directives
- Three apache instances acting as backends listening on the various ports

The `mod_proxy` configuration is identical to what you've shown:

```
ProxyPass /appOne http://localhost:9999/
ProxyPassReverse /appOne http://localhost:9999/

ProxyPass /appTwo http://localhost:9000/
ProxyPassReverse /appTwo http://localhost:9000/

ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
```

The only difference of note is that I haven't configured an SSL context for my frontend server.  Other than the two examples you've shown in your question, are there any other `VirtualHost` blocks in your configuration (in particular, other virtual hosts configured on port 443)?